Critical case of Galton-Watson Process
I'm reading the proof in Artheya, Branching Process (but I think this is a classical result) of the exponential limit law in the critical case of the Galton-Watson process i.e :
$\mathcal{L}(Z_n \vert Z_n > 0) \underset{n \to \infty}{\to} \mathcal{E}(2/\sigma^2)$.
I don't understand why in the proof we can say that :
$$ \mathbb{E}[e^{tZ_n / n} \vert Z_n > 0] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[e^{tZ_n / n} \mathbb{1}_{Z_n > 0}]}{\mathbb{P}(Z_n > 0)}  $$
In the critical case, $\mathbb{P}(Z_n = 0)$ converges to 1 as $n \to +\infty$. Is $\mathbb{P}(Z_n =0) \neq 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$? Otherwise, the quantity above would not be defined and we should say :
$$ \mathbb{E}[e^{tZ_n / n} \vert Z_n > 0] = \frac{\mathbb{E}[e^{tZ_n / n} \mathbb{1}_{Z_n > 0}]}{\mathbb{P}(Z_n > 0)} \mathbb{1}_{Z_n > 0} $$ (I think)
Am I missing something?

If $P(Z_k=0)=1$ for some $k$ then  $P(Z_n=0)=1$ for all $n\ge k$ and $\mathcal L (Z_n|Z_n >0)$ is undefined for $n\ge k$. I suppose this trivial case is excluded in this theorem. [I don't have the book with me for conformation]. Your last equaiton also does not make sense in this  special case.

Ok, thank you. I don't know where this case is excluded in the book but I understand why it is trivial.
